# tflite equivalent for kernel = torch.FloatTensor or similar

Tags: tensorflow-lite, google-coral

When processing images,

Python torch can create Laplacian or Gaussian pyramids using

kernel = torch.FloatTensor or similar

ie with models, learning etc.

How can one do this with tflite as a precursor to learning?

my use case is microprocessor, but anything would make a start!!

thanks

I've been searching for any usage, in books and online, but not found anything obviously appropriate.